# How can I add multiple linear layouts with imageviews dynamically?

Tags: android, arrays, layout, imageview

I am trying to add images to my app based on a previously entered string.

This is for my final year project where I am going to take speech input from a user and present them with the BSL fingerspelling translation for their input. Currently I am just trying to get the translation part working, the speech to text function can come later.

I expect the app to be able to take my text input, break that down into individual characters, then check each character to see what letter it is and then display the corresponding image for that letter in the output window. The images should be shown next to one another and start a new line automatically when the sequence reaches the end of the page.

Comment: You can use a recyclerview and linearLayout as the viewHolder to dynamically add views.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a linear layout for this case.
Try to using RecyclerView and grid layout manager if all your images views have the same size or StaggeredGridLayoutManager If your image views have different size.

Please, check this link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager

Welcome to the Android world.